# Spring validation annotation using message with parameters

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-validator

I'm trying to use annotations with a custom message in spring/hibernate validation. What I want to do is support internationalization while being able to pass in a parameter.

For instance, here is the field in the java class:

```
@NotEmpty (message = "{error.required}")
public String name;
```

*ValidationMessages.properties* has this:

```
error.required = {0} is a required field
```

So I'm looking for a way to pass in the field name into that message using the message annotation in the java class. Is this even possible?

EDIT: Similar you this question: [JSR 303 Bean Validation in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467861/jsr-303-bean-validation-in-spring)